# Is it possible to get info about errors more than 7 days in the past?

Tags: curl, newrelic

I am using the New Relic API to get information about errors on a client's site. From what I can find on the New Relic website, the only metric/field combination that would be relevant is  Errors/all (metric) and errors_per_minute (field). I make the following API call to receive information about a week long period:

curl -H "api-key-x:KEY" "api.newrelic.com/api/v1/accounts//metrics/data.xml?begin=&end=&metrics=Errors/all&field=errors_per_minute&agent_id=&summary=1"

This gives me a single value, errors_per_minute, that I use to determine the errors in a week for this web app. I would like to be able to see what the types of these errors are but Newrelic.com only has information on errors for the past 7 days. Is it possible for me to obtain this information? It doesn't have to be via API call, it would be sufficient if there were just a way to ask New Relic to display them on their site. Thanks in advance.

If it is not possible, what reason would new relic have for only storing the information for a week? I understand that this question sounds specific, but I believe it would be useful for anyone who obtains information from the API and either wants to check that it is correct or find out more about the statistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible to get errors per minute beyond 7 days in the past using New Relic's API.  This is because New Relic rolls up minute-level data into hour-long increments after 7 days:

https://newrelic.com/docs/subscriptions/data-retention

You can of course get errors_per_minute for anytime in the past 90 days - it'll just be an
average over the smallest available block (or a larger one if you're asking per day).

Error and transaction traces are only stored for 7 days.  You might file a support ticket with New Relic making a feature request for the functionality you describe.